# Things that i should change in view while upgrading laravel 5.6 to laravel 8?

Tags: php, laravel, upgrade, laravel-blade

I had a project in laravel 5.7. I made a new laravel 8 project and transfered all models,controllers, migrations and views manually. When i serve that project following error comes,
** "ErrorException
Attempt to read property "title" on string (View: project_laravel8/resources/views/app.blade.php) **
note: i didn't made any change in views.

Comment: You have to follow every step from upgrade guide in certain order: first [5.8](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/upgrade), then [6.x](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/upgrade), then [7.x](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/upgrade), then [8.x](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/upgrade).

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would do this but it will take time.

1. start a new project with laravel 8,
2. make all controllers and models that you need, copy and paste each controller and model codes, one by one keep testing where something break.
3. it will take you more time but it will be effecient

Comment: Thank you, I did the same.